# UILocalNotification showing only once

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I have one app to manage some iBeacons and send to me notifications.

My problem is that i don´t know why when in background it only shows me one notification. It does not show another one again until i restart the program.

The code is as it follows.
The following code requires for permission.

```
if(application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")) {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
            UIUserNotificationSettings(
                forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge,
                categories: nil
            )
        )
    }
```

This is the function that allows me to send notifications

```
func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message: String!){
    let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = message
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    NSLog("\(message)")
}
```

And switch in the didRangeBeacons function

```
switch(nearestBeacon.minor){
        case 40899:
            for v in iceAds{
                if (!v.accepted && v.zone == zone){
                    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("\(v.nameAd):  \(v.descriptionAd)")
                    beaconAd = v
                    showAd()

                    return
                }
            }
            break;
        case 21750:
            for v in blueberryAds{
                if (!v.accepted && v.zone == zone){
                    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("\(v.nameAd):  \(v.descriptionAd)")
                    beaconAd = v
                    showAd()

                    return
                }
            }
            break;
        case 47846:
            for v in mintAds{
                if (!v.accepted && v.zone == zone){
                    beaconAd = v
                    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("\(v.nameAd):  \(v.descriptionAd)")
                    showAd()

                    return
                }

            }
            if (zone == 3){
                if (newProdArray()){
                    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("Veja os produtos que lhe faltam comprar")
                    showListAdded()
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return
        }
```

I have also enabled background capabilities (location updates and uses bluetooth LE accessories). Also added the Required background Modes to my plist file.

I would be very grateful if you can point me out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can range idenfinitly in background -- background mode BLE isn't needed for iBeacon anyway

ranging like that would also drain the battery a lot

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you can. I done it in other apps. I am not understanding.